# Unable to get RabbitMQ running on Windows 10

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, erlang

I've run the Erlang and RabbitMQ installers "As Administrator".
Both seem to have installed correctly.
The RabbitMQ server is running.
However, when I run any command line Rabbit commands (rabbitmqctl, rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management, etc.), I get the following error message/dump.  I obviously cannot access the Management Console or communicate with the service at all.

Any ideas on the below error and what could be causing this?  I've installed on other Win10 machines before without any issues.

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 20-Jun-2018::10:08:39.865000 ===
supervisor: {local,'Elixir.Logger.Supervisor'}
errorContext: start_error
reason: noproc
offender: [{pid,undefined},
           {id,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler'},
           {mfargs,
               {'Elixir.Logger.Watcher',start_link,
                   [{error_logger,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',
                        {true,false,500}}]}},
           {restart_type,permanent},
           {shutdown,5000},
           {child_type,worker}]
=CRASH REPORT==== 20-Jun-2018::10:08:39.865000 ===
  crasher:
   initial call: application_master:init/4
   pid: <0.80.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{shutdown,
                         {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',
                             noproc}},
                     {'Elixir.Logger.App',start,[normal,[]]}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 
138)
    ancestors: [<0.79.0>]
    message_queue_len: 1
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.81.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.79.0>,<0.42.0>]
    dictionary: []
   trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 193
  neighbours:
=CRASH REPORT==== 20-Jun-2018::10:08:39.865000 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: Elixir.Logger.Watcher:init/1
    pid: <0.87.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: noproc
      in function  gen:do_for_proc/2 (gen.erl, line 228)
      in call from gen_event:rpc/2 (gen_event.erl, line 239)
      in call from 'Elixir.Logger.Watcher':init/1 (lib/logger/watcher.ex, 
line 23)
      in call from gen_server:init_it/2 (gen_server.erl, line 374)
      in call from gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 342)
    ancestors: ['Elixir.Logger.Supervisor',<0.81.0>]
    message_queue_len: 0
    messages: []
    links: [<0.82.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 254
  neighbours:
=INFO REPORT==== 20-Jun-2018::10:08:39.881000 ===
    application: logger
    exited: {{shutdown,

{failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',noproc}},
             {'Elixir.Logger.App',start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: temporary
Could not start application logger: Logger.App.start(:normal, []) returned an 
error: shutdown: failed to start child: Logger.ErrorHandler
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process 
currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application 
isn't started
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Already tried reinstalling the service on Windows as suggested on other questions but to no avail.

Comment: having the same issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also encountered this problem yesterday after installing the latest version of RabbitMQ onto a Windows 10 box.  Finally found the cause this morning:  It's related to the version of the Erlang OTP that I had installed (the latest - 21.0).  Apparently the version of Elixir used by RabbitMQ has issues with this version of the Erlang OTP - at least that's the conclusion I came to after reading [this thread here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7638).

After uninstalling that erlang version, and installing version 19.3 from [this page](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html), I was able to use the RabbitMQ console commands without this error message being thrown every time.  (I did however have to fix the `ERLANG_HOME` environment variable also... the uninstall/reinstall of erlang had for some reason left this pointing at the old (v21) folder which no longer existed.)

Comment: cant find the download link, says they are working on the page :(

Comment: okay, got it working. @Sandra was right. install otp_win64_19.3.exe for now.

Run the following commands:

  `SET HOMEDRIVE=C: |
  rabbitmq-service remove |
  rabbitmq-service install |
  rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management`

Comment: Just to close this out (in case someone else comes across this later), after installing the new (old) version and running the command that @FrankDupree suggested, I had to re-install the RabbitMQ server, re-enable the management console plugin and now things appear to be working perfectly.  Thanks to all!!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Except that I used Erlang v20.3 which appears to be the latest version that works with RabbitMQ. There's info about compatible Erlang versions on this page https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Answer (score 1):

I got a bonus error with erlang 19.3 :

```
λ rabbitmq-service install
C:\Programs\erl8.3\erts-8.3\bin\erlsrv: Service RabbitMQ added to system.
bad "MBa" value: ageffcbf
Usage: beam.smp.dll [flags] [ -- [init_args] ]
```

However the service installed and started successfully with no side effects so far.